Unable to deploy my ERC721 contract, asking for high txn fees
Hi: I have written a ERC721 smart contract and am trying to deploy it on ETH sepolia network as it is under development. But high txn fee is being asked around 1 ETH. I have tried lots of approach but always fee is asking for 0.9/1/1.234 ETH. Here is the full contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    uint256 public commissionPercentage = 2; // 2% commission

    struct Offer {
        address offerer;
        uint256 offerAmount;
    }
    
    struct NFTDetails {
        uint256 tokenId;
        string tokenURI;
        uint256 price;
        address owner;
    }
 struct Collection {
        string name;
        string description;
        address creator;
        uint256[] nftIds;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public itemPrices;
    mapping(uint256 => Offer) public offers;
    mapping(uint256 => address) public creators;
    mapping(uint256 => Collection) public collections; // Collection ID to Collection

    uint256 public collectionCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM") {
        tokenCounter = 0;
        collectionCounter = 0;
    }

function createCollection(string memory _name, string memory _description) public returns (uint256) {
    collections[collectionCounter] = Collection({
        name: _name,
        description: _description,
        creator: msg.sender,
        nftIds: new uint256[](0)
    });
    collectionCounter++;
    return collectionCounter - 1;
}

    // Mint an NFT and associate with a collection (optional)
    function createNFT(string memory tokenURI, uint256 collectionId) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        creators[newItemId] = msg.sender;
        tokenCounter++;

        // Associate NFT with a collection if collectionId is valid
        if (collectionId < collectionCounter) {
            collections[collectionId].nftIds.push(newItemId);
         }

        return newItemId;
    }
    function listItemForSale(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner of this NFT");
        require(price > 0, "Price should be greater than zero");
        itemPrices[tokenId] = price;
    }

    function buyNFT(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint256 price = itemPrices[tokenId];
        address seller = ownerOf(tokenId);

        require(price > 0, "This item is not for sale");
        require(msg.value >= price, "Insufficient funds to buy this NFT");

        uint256 commission = (msg.value * commissionPercentage) / 100;
        uint256 sellerAmount = msg.value - commission;

        _transfer(seller, msg.sender, tokenId);
        payable(owner()).transfer(commission);
        payable(seller).transfer(sellerAmount);

        itemPrices[tokenId] = 0;  // Remove from sale list
        delete offers[tokenId];
    }

    function makeOffer(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        require(itemPrices[tokenId] > 0, "This item is not for sale");
        require(msg.value > 0, "Offer amount should be greater than zero");

        Offer memory existingOffer = offers[tokenId];

        // Check if the new offer is higher than the existing offer
        require(msg.value > existingOffer.offerAmount, "There is already a higher or equal offer");

        // Refund the previous offer
        if (existingOffer.offerAmount > 0) {
            payable(existingOffer.offerer).call{value:existingOffer.offerAmount}("");
        }

        // Update with the new offer
        offers[tokenId] = Offer(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function acceptOffer(uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner of this NFT");
        Offer memory offer = offers[tokenId];
        require(offer.offerAmount > 0, "No offer made");

        uint256 commission = (offer.offerAmount * commissionPercentage) / 100;
        uint256 sellerAmount = offer.offerAmount - commission;

        _transfer(msg.sender, offer.offerer, tokenId);
        payable(owner()).transfer(commission);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(sellerAmount);

        itemPrices[tokenId] = 0;
        delete offers[tokenId];
    }

    function withdrawOffer(uint256 tokenId) public {
        Offer memory offer = offers[tokenId];
        require(offer.offerer == msg.sender, "You did not make this offer");

        payable(msg.sender).transfer(offer.offerAmount);
        delete offers[tokenId];
    }

    function getMyNFTs() public view returns (NFTDetails[] memory owned, NFTDetails[] memory created, NFTDetails[] memory onSale) {
        uint256 totalSupply = tokenCounter;
        uint256 ownedCount = 0;
        uint256 createdCount = 0;
        uint256 onSaleCount = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            if (ownerOf(i) == msg.sender) {
                ownedCount++;
            }
            if (creators[i] == msg.sender) {
                createdCount++;
            }
            if (itemPrices[i] > 0 && ownerOf(i) == msg.sender) {
                onSaleCount++;
            }
        }

        owned = new NFTDetails[](ownedCount);
        created = new NFTDetails[](createdCount);
        onSale = new NFTDetails[](onSaleCount);

        uint256 ownedIndex = 0;
        uint256 createdIndex = 0;
        uint256 onSaleIndex = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            address nftOwner = ownerOf(i);
            if (nftOwner == msg.sender) {
                owned[ownedIndex] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], nftOwner);
                ownedIndex++;
            }
            if (creators[i] == msg.sender) {
                created[createdIndex] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], nftOwner);
                createdIndex++;
            }
            if (itemPrices[i] > 0 && nftOwner == msg.sender) {
                onSale[onSaleIndex] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], nftOwner);
                onSaleIndex++;
            }
        }
        return (owned, created, onSale);
    }

    function getAllNFTs() public view returns (NFTDetails[] memory) {
        uint256 totalSupply = tokenCounter;
        NFTDetails[] memory allNFTs = new NFTDetails[](totalSupply);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            allNFTs[i] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], ownerOf(i));
        }

        return allNFTs;
    }

    function getOffer(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address offerer, uint256 offerAmount) {
        Offer memory offer = offers[tokenId];
        return (offer.offerer, offer.offerAmount);
    }
   function transferNFT(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
    require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner of this NFT");
    _transfer(msg.sender, to, tokenId);
}

// Function to get the commission rate
    function getCommissionRate() public view returns (uint256) {
        return commissionPercentage;
    }

    // Function to set the commission rate (only owner)
    function setCommissionRate(uint256 _commissionRate) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner(), "Only owner can set commission rate");
        commissionPercentage = _commissionRate;
    }
   
   function isOwner(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return account == owner();
    }

function getCollectionsBasic(uint8 flag) public view returns (uint256[] memory collectionIds) {
    uint256 totalCollections = collectionCounter;
    uint256 collectionCount = 0;

    // Depending on the flag, either count "my collections" or all collections
    if (flag == 1) {
        // Count how many collections the user has created (for "My Collections")
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalCollections; i++) {
            if (collections[i].creator == msg.sender) {
                collectionCount++;
            }
        }
    } else if (flag == 2) {
        // For all collections, no filtering is needed
        collectionCount = totalCollections;
    }

    // Create an array to store the collection IDs
    collectionIds = new uint256[](collectionCount);
    uint256 index = 0;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalCollections; i++) {
        if (flag == 2 || (flag == 1 && collections[i].creator == msg.sender)) {
            collectionIds[index] = i; // Store the collection ID
            index++;
        }
    }
    
    return collectionIds;
}

function getCollectionAndNFTDetails(uint256 collectionId) public view returns (
    string memory name, 
    string memory description, 
    address creator, 
    uint256[] memory nftIds, 
    NFTDetails[] memory nfts
) {
    require(collectionId < collectionCounter, "Collection does not exist");

    Collection memory collection = collections[collectionId];
    NFTDetails[] memory nftDetailsArray = new NFTDetails[](collection.nftIds.length);

    // Loop through all the NFTs in the collection and retrieve their details
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < collection.nftIds.length; i++) {
        uint256 nftId = collection.nftIds[i];
        nftDetailsArray[i] = NFTDetails(nftId, tokenURI(nftId), itemPrices[nftId], ownerOf(nftId));
    }

    return (
        collection.name, 
        collection.description, 
        collection.creator, 
        collection.nftIds, 
        nftDetailsArray
    );
}



}

Any suggestion for this?
Thanks!

The gas price is quite high at this moment, >300 GWEI, not something to be fixed by someone, You can try to downsize your contract, or just use a different testnet with a lower gas price.

try holesky testnet, it very cheap

Ok. I will try. Is it something in my contract which leads gas consumption more? Because I have optimized the contract  by different ways. Still getting same issue. If it works well in holesky  testnet then in mainnet will it work?

No, your contract is logically fine, it comes under the limit. Also I tried deploying it on holesky, Here is the tx. The gas price is quite cheap. Although there's always a room for optimization. You can try downsizing the contract for fun and learning.

If you see extremely high gas prices while deploying a contract, it's probably because something is wrong with your constructor.
In your case, you are using the latest version of Ownable but not passing the "initialOwner" address to the constructor. Ownable contract now requires this. Fix your constructor like the one below, and you can deploy without a problem if there are no other problems.
constructor() ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM") Ownable(msg.sender) {
    tokenCounter = 0;
    collectionCounter = 0;
}

Apart from that constructor error, your contract has potential reentrancy vulnerability in buyNFT and acceptOffer functions:

In the buyNFT and acceptOffer functions, you transfer the NFT ownership (_transfer(seller, msg.sender, tokenId) and _transfer(msg.sender, offer.offerer, tokenId)) before transferring funds (payable(owner()).transfer(commission) and payable(seller).transfer(sellerAmount)).
This order opens up a reentrancy vulnerability where the external contract (if malicious) could call back into your contract before the rest of the logic is executed.
To fix this, you should update state variables and transfer funds before calling _transfer, or use ReentrancyGuard from OpenZeppelin to protect these functions from reentrancy.


It's working now..
